# One TextView per line in LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am currently starting an Android app and want to build a list where each item occupies one single row. Right now I only have a TextView but will have more elements later.

I am having problems in placing one element per row since the TextViews just get placed one after the other, like this:

[Android View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un2CV.jpg)

The layout for this is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twitterNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code for the RecyclerView is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="codehero.twitteralarmclock.ui.main.tweet.TweetsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ui.main.tweet.TweetsFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_tweets" />
```

I've tried changing the orientation of the LinearLayout, adding the maxLines and singleLine attributes to the TextView but nothing changed.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: show your adapters code, looks like wrong `LayoutManager` set for `RecyclerView`. in posted XML almost everything is fine - `TextView` should have height set to `wrap_content` (this won't fix your issue, but will perform better)

Comment: @snachmsm just edited with the RecyclerView code

Comment: show Java/Kotlin side, adapter and how do you init it and attach to `RecyclerView`

Comment: I saw what's wrong, Android Studio default code for a FragmentList was creating a GridLayout if the list had more than 1 item. I changed to always create a LinearLayout. Thanks for pointing to check that code out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns the Android Studio default FragmentList code will create a GridLayout if the list count is bigger than 1:

```
class TweetsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tweets_list, container, false)

        // Set the adapter
        if (view is RecyclerView) {
            with(view) {
                layoutManager = when {
                    columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
                }
                adapter = TweetsViewAdapter(TwitterPlaceholderContent.ITEMS)
            }
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

The solution is to always create a LinearLayout inside the onCreateView method:

```
if (view is RecyclerView) {
    with(view) {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        adapter = TweetsViewAdapter(TwitterPlaceholderContent.ITEMS)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the linear layout to a constraint layout like so and re run the code and check

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/twitterNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If this still doesn't solve your issue try to get rid of the text appearance attribute and layout margin attribute and recompile.

If it works then you know it's a problem of the attributes

If it still does not solve you might have to paste your adapter code

Comment: The problem was the default Android Studio code when creating a FragmentList. It created a GridLayout when the list has more than 1 element. Thanks for taking your time to answer though!